# Change Opacity of JWPlayer Display Icon (Play Button)

Tags: javascript, css, jwplayer

I want to change the opacity of the JW Player Display Icon (the play button) from 1 to .35 and want to avoid making my own skin. I don't see anything about opacity or any example code in the docs here: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413071-skin-xml-reference#dispaly

I can easily change the opacity in Chrome's Dev Tools by finding the jwdisplayIcon class and changing the opacity. Running this line in Chrome's console also works:

```
$('.jwdisplayIcon').css('opacity', '.35');
```

But I tried adding the same line to my JavaScript and it didn't work. I also tried adding the following to my CSS and it didn't work:

```
.jwdisplayIcon {
  opacity: .35;
}
```

This is the inherited setup I have:

```
    jwplayer("expert-video").setup({
        sources: [
          {% for media in medias %}
            {file: "{{ media.media.url }}", label: "{{ media.name }}"},
          {% endfor %}
        ],
        {% if expert.media_poster %}
          image: "{{ expert.media_poster.url }}",
        {% endif %}
        width: "100%",
        aspectratio: "16:9",
        abouttext: "&copy; Copyright 2014",
        aboutlink: "http://example.com",
        skin: "vapor"
      });
```

It seems like this JavaScript setup would be the place to make changes, but I don't know what to add. I tried adding the following line to the setup, but the browser threw an Unexpected Token on the '()' (it seems like this can only be called inside an event?):

```
jwplayer().getPlugin("display").style.opacity='.35';
```

I tried adding the following to my setup even though it would target the whole player instead of just the display icon, and it did nothing at all:

```
opacity: ".35",
```

I found [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramp/nF7Mw/) to play with JW Player and changed the `icons: false` to the following, but it did not work:

```
 icons: {
     opacity: .35,
 }
```

What do I need to do to change the opacity without building a new skin?

Comment: `icons` needs to be a boolean value. An object literal of {opacity:.35} at this point is useless. Also there’s a comma at the end…

Comment: Just a note to anyone who finds this question: adding !important to the CSS style will work, but it will cause the display icon to be there even when the video is playing, so don't do that.

Comment: Yeah, using !important can have weird side effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the graphic in photoshop or another image editing program and change the opacity there.

That way it will work in both rendering modes in the player, Flash or HTML5.

Your CSS work arounds here will only work for the HTML5 player.

Yes, you would have to build a new skin in order to do this, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ethan, I did what you said—I saved images with a lighter opacity, encoded them, put them in vapor.xml and set "skin" to the path of the vapor.xml file in the JW Player setup JavaScript. The new images show up when I serve the site locally, but when I push all the changes to the staging server, the default images still show up. What can I do? Is this an XSS problem?

Comment: Do you have a link I can look at?

Comment: Here you can see staging vs. localhost (both have the same code): http://pbrd.co/1BrlxoQ 

Here's the link to the staging page: http://stagingpy.zana.io/lessons/building-unicorn/mission/

Comment: Your skin is loading from - http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/12/skins/vapor.xml, so this is the unmodified version. Looking at your source, this file - static/js/step_detail.01f6e4005617.js, is loading the skin like this - skin:"vapor", this will load the skin from our CDN. You need to change this to something like, skin:"your/site/vapor.xml", and then have the skin uploaded to that location (as well as all skin images, unless you already base 64 encoded them).

Comment: I just double-checked every file that has the word "vapor" in it on staging, and they all look like this: skin: "/static/js/vapor.xml". That XML file has the base 64 encoded images in it, and like I said, they're showing up locally, but not from staging. Why would the skin be loading from p.jwpcdn.com/6/12/skins/vapor.xml instead of from the edited file? I couldn't find that link anywhere in the code.

Comment: Weirdly, it looks like it's looking for the file and failing on this page: http://stagingpy.zana.io/experts/matt-mullenweg/

Comment: It looks like that file does not exist - "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://stagingpy.zana.io/static/js/vapor.xml", but on your first link, you are not referencing the skin XML file on your staging server, you are simply loading skin: "vapor", which will load from our CDN by default. I recommend updating your player setup code to point to an absolute URL to the skin, to confirm that it works.